# extract map contents based on a list key input

Tags: groovy

I am trying to get age as map element based on age list input, i have tried below code but not working..

```
def people = [[name:'Bob', age: 32, gender: 'M'],[name:'john', age: 42, gender: 'M']]
def id = ["age"]
def age = people.subMap(id).values().flatten()

println age
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough

Comment: My desired output should be a map of age elements like [[age:32,age:42]]

Comment: You can't have a map that contains duplicated keys. You could extract a list of ages e.g. `people.age` would produce a list `[32,42]`.

Comment: on the same lines, I have def people = [[name:'Bob', age: 32, gender: 'M'] and def id = ["name","age"] , i just need name and age as new submap.. is it possible.. thanks for clarifying about duplicates